# Error query SQL parsing XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I get the following error trying to traverse the xml and inserting each node in the DB.

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

the lines of the error are these:

> $ninv= $obra->ninventario."/".$obra->ncatalogo;
>
> $consulta ="INSERT INTO `bcficha` (`ninv`, `contrato`, `desc`,
>   `tecnica`, `pieza`, `dimen`, `lochab`, `ubicacion`) VALUES
>   ('".$ninv."','".$obra->contrato."','".$obra->titulo."','".$obra->tecnica."','".$obra->tipo."','".$obra->medidas_con_marco."',
>   '".$obra->localizacion_habitual.", '".$obra->ultima_localizacion."');
>   ";

The XML file goes through it perfectly because I have comporbado with an echo and one of the parameters of the node.

I do not know if it's a problem with the connection with the BD, which I think not, or it's a problem of another type.

```
<?php

$fichero = "./obras.xml";
if(!$xml = simplexml_load_file($fichero))
{
    echo "No se ha podido cargar el archivo <br>";
} 
else 
{
    echo "El archivo se ha cargado correctamente <br>";
}

include"./conectar.php";
$enlace= conectarse();

foreach ($xml as $obra)
{
    $obra = (array) $obra;
    $ninv= $obra->ninventario."/".$obra->ncatalogo;

    $consulta ="INSERT INTO `bcficha` (`ninv`, `contrato`, `desc`, `tecnica`, `pieza`, `dimen`, `lochab`, `ubicacion`) VALUES ('".$ninv."','".$obra->contrato."','".$obra->titulo."','".$obra->tecnica."','".$obra->tipo."','".$obra->medidas_con_marco."', '".$obra->localizacion_habitual.", '".$obra->ultima_localizacion."'); ";

    $resultado= mysqli_query($enlace,$consulta) or die (mysqli_error);
    if ($resultado)
    {
        echo ("Base de datos caragda correctamente<br>");
    }
    else
    {
        echo ("Eror cargando base de datos<br>");
    }   
}    
?>
```

and conectar.php

```
<?php

    function conectarse()
    {
       if (!($conexion=mysql_connect("localhost","root","")))
       {
          echo "Error conectando a la base de datos<br>";
          exit();
       }

        if (mysql_select_db("db1", $conexion)) 
       {
           echo("<br>Conectado !!!<br>");
       }
       else
       {
            echo("Fallo al conectar<br>");
       }

       return $conexion;
    }

?>
```

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: there is a **line number** in the error message. did you notice that?

Comment: @YourCommonSense i'm sorry, i will notice it

Comment: then try to think what does `$obra = (array) $obra;`  do

Comment: @YourCommonSense i want to covert $obra in array to save in the array all xml registers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have converted `$obra` to an array here:

```
foreach ($xml as $obra)
{
    $obra = (array) $obra;
[...]
```

so you **need** to use that variable as an array:

```
$ninv = $obra['ninventario'] . '/' . $obra['ncatalogo'];
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

i think your problem is `$obra` and `$obra` is not an object.its an array